# JQUERY images fadeIn

Tags: jquery

it was meant to be really simple, but after a long day at work I could just not figure it out. I have two questions, one, is there a better way to do it (I'm sure there is) and two, with the code provided, how would I get it to loop to start from the beginning of the script again. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

It basically has a top text area that rotates through, with a subheading fading in a couple of seconds later, both which will then fade out together, followed by different text but same treatment.

Please find the fiddle link below, without working images, sorry, its not been hosted and I cant remember my FTP details.

http://jsfiddle.net/mZ6uy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just post a quick in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mZ6uy/2
This is not the best one but it answer your two questions.

Comment: OMG, 1st time use it, just save it again, please check

Comment: Haha, I think when you save it, it should have updated the URL, any chance you have it?